# SAS %DS2CSV Macro controlling decimal format

Tags: sas

Is there a way to control the format for output when calling %ds2csv?

If all numerical data are stored as float, and some variables storing only integers, is there any way to ensure that "2" is output as 2 and not 1.999999996 or some other value that rounds to 2?

Another use case: ensure that variables storing decimal values are rounded to desired scale in the resulting csv.

I am happy to RTFM but the %ds2csv documentation doesn't seem to address?

Comment: Huh?  That macro is just going generate a normal PUT statement that uses whatever format you have attached to the variable.  So if you want the variables displayed differently then change the format you have attached to them.

Comment: I have never used sas before. I am a dba assigned to import dozens of sas "tables?" With thousands of variables. I need a way to document what will happen when we run %ds2csv on any given table including  max total digits and max decimal digits and how to guarantee integer only

Comment: Import into what?  Why not just have SAS write the data into the target instead of generating intermediate files?  Are you sure you want to round the values to integers instead of transferring the actual value?

Comment: How do we generate create table statements with proper data type for integers, decimals etc?

Comment: The details depend on what database you are using.  If you have SAS/Access to XXX (whatever database you are using) then SAS could attempt to create the table directly.  But no matter what you will need to do the final decision making about which of the extended data types the database has you want to use. SAS only has fixed length strings and floating point nunbers.  So you need to know the actual data to know if other types could be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set or modify the format of the variables in your dataset dataset before saving it as a csv with the macro.

```
data have;
    input float int;
    format float 8.;
    datalines;
1.999999996 5
1.8587232 4
;
run;

/* Alternative method for an existing dataset.
   Not needed if you already used the format statement */
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    modify have;
        format float 8.;
quit;

%ds2csv(data=have, runmode=b, csvfile="/folder/want.csv");
```

Comment: Is this format then available via dictionary. Columns? Can you please add format commands for a)forcing integer only and b) precision 18 , scale 4?

Comment: Is precision 18, scale 4 achieved using "format 19.4"? 19 is width including decimal point?

Comment: If by precision 18 you mean you have 18 significant digits then you might have a problem.  SAS numbers can only store just shy of 16 significant digits.  You can write out 18 digits, but don't expect to be able them all to be correct in those extra digits.

Comment: FORMAT width includes all characters. So 19.4 will have room for 18 digits for positive numbers and 17 digits for negative numbers.

Comment: `19.4` means its total width is 19, including the decimal point and a minus sign. `.4` indicates the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. `format` controls only how the value is displayed to the user. Any math done on it in SAS will be done on the raw value. It just also happens to control how that value looks when exporting it as a csv.

Comment: @StuSztukowski - will this format then appear in dictionary.Columns?

Comment: Yes, dictionary.columns will update with this new format.

Comment: I will accept this answer asap after I test it out thanks!